# Fiz esse código e tá rodando, mas a parte do else não funciona. Quando digito uma entrada invalida dá erro no meu código invés de mostrar a mensagem

Tags: python, condição, else

```
print("BEM VINDO!")
print("*" * 40)
player_1 = input("Player 1: Qual o seu Nome? ")
player_2 = input("Player 2: Qual o seu Nome? ")
entradasValidas = ('Pedra','Papel', 'Tesoura', 'Lagarto', 'Esponja')
print('''Considerando as seguintes escolhas como válidas:
[0] Pedra 
[1] Papel 
[2] Tesoura
[3] Lagarto 
[4] Esponja''')
player_1 = int(input("Player 1: Qual sua Escolha? "))
player_2 = int(input("Player 2: Qual sua Escolha? "))
print("*" * 40)
print("Player_1 Escolheu: {}".format(entradasValidas[player_1]))
print("Player_2 Escolheu: {}".format(entradasValidas[player_2]))
print("*" * 40)
if player_1 == 0: # jogador 1 jogou Pedra
    if player_2 == 0:
      print("Temos um Empate!")
    elif player_2 == 1 or player_2 == 4:
      print("O Jogador 2 Venceu!")
    elif player_2 == 2 or player_2 == 3:
      print("O Jogador 1 Venceu!")
    else:
      print("Ops! Essa jodada está inválida. Tente novamente!")


if player_1 == 1: # jogador 1 jogou Papel 
    if player_2 == 0 or player_2 == 4:
      print("O Jogador 1 Venceu!")
    elif player_2 == 1:
      print("Temos um Empate!")
    elif player_2 == 2 or player_2 == 3:
      print("O Jogador 2 Venceu!")
    else:
      print("Ops! Essa jodada está inválida. Tente novamente!")
 

if player_1 == 2: # jogador 1 jogou Tesoura 
    if player_2 == 0:
      print("O Jogador 2 Venceu!")
    elif player_2 == 1 or player_2 == 3 or player_2 == 4:
      print("O Jogador 1 Venceu!")
    elif player_2 == 2:
      print("Temos um Empate!")
    else:
      print("Ops! Essa jodada está inválida. Tente novamente!")



if player_1 == 3: # jogador 1 jogou Lagarto 
    if player_2 == 0 or player_2 == 2:
      print("O Jogador 2 Venceu!")
    elif player_2 == 1 or player_2 == 4:
      print("O jogador 1 Venceu!")
    elif player_2 == 3:
      print("Temos um Empate!")
    else:
      print("Ops! Essa jodada está inválida. Tente novamente!")



if player_1 == 4: # jogador 1 jogou Esponja
    if player_2 == 0 or player_2 == 2:
      print("O Jogador 1 Venceu!")
    elif player_2 == 1 or player_2 == 3:
      print("O Jogador 2 Venceu!")
    elif player_2 == 4:
      print("Temos um Empate!")
    else:
      print("Ops! Essa jodada está inválida. Tente novamente!")

print("")
print("*" * 40)
```

Comment: Sua pergunta parece ter alguns problemas e sua experiência aqui no Stack Overflow em Português poderá não ser a melhor por causa disso. Queremos que você se dê bem aqui e consiga o que quer, mas para isso precisamos que você faça a sua parte. Veja algumas orientações que vão te ajudar: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045) ([versão curta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/101)). Lei a [Como debugar programas pequenos](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7785/137387) e faça o nosso [tour].

Answer (score -3):

Eu fiz um jokenpo há um tempo atras, veja se te ajuda

```
from random import randint
import time
itens=('\u270A', '\u270B', '\u270C\uFE0F')
computador = randint(0, 2)
print(' \U0001f3b2 \U0001f3ae'*5)
jogador = int(input('''   Escolha sua jogada:
   [ 0 ] \u270A
   [ 1 ] \u270B
   [ 2 ] \u270C\uFE0F\n   Sua escolha: '''))
 print('-='*15)
 print('LOADING', end='')
 time.sleep(1)
 print(' .', end='')
 time.sleep(1)
 print(' .', end='')
 time.sleep(1)
 print(' .')
 print('Já escolhi, VAMOS?')
 time.sleep(1.5)
 print('JO')
 time.sleep(1.2)
 print('KEN')
 time.sleep(1.5)
 print('POOO')
 print(itens[computador])
 time.sleep(1)
 if computador == 0:
   if jogador == 0:
     print('EMPATE!')
   elif jogador == 1:
       print('JOGADOR VENCEU!')
   else:
       print('COMPUTADOR VENCEU!')  
 if computador == 1:
   if jogador == 0:
     print('COMPUTADOR VENCEU!')
   elif jogador == 1:
       print('EMPATE!')
   else:
       print('JOGADOR VENCEU!')  
 if computador == 2: 
   if jogador == 0:
     print('JOGADOR VENCEU!')
   elif jogador == 1:
     print('COMPUTADOR VENCEU!')
   else:
     print('EMPATE!')
```

Comment: Obrigada, me ajudou bastante *-* 
Consegui implementar algumas coisas no meu código pra ficar mais legal com isso

Answer (score -3):

Creio que a condição está sem sentido, não há um laço de repetição, depois do tente novamente de qualquer forma o programa encerra.

Coloquei um while True e um tratamento para exceção try except no início, assim só cai nas condições após a entrada de dados correta por parte do usuário.

```py
print("BEM VINDO!")
print("*" * 40)
jog_1 = input("Player 1: Qual o seu Nome? ")
jog_2 = input("Player 2: Qual o seu Nome? ")
entradasValidas = ['Pedra', 'Papel', 'Tesoura', 'Lagarto', 'Esponja']
print('''Considerando as seguintes escolhas como válidas:
[0] Pedra 
[1] Papel 
[2] Tesoura
[3] Lagarto 
[4] Esponja''')
while True:
    try:
        player_1 = int(input("{}: Qual sua Escolha? ".format(jog_1)))
        player_2 = int(input("{}: Qual sua Escolha? ".format(jog_2)))
        if player_1 != 0 and player_1 != 1 and player_1 != 2 and player_1 != 3 and player_1 != 4:
            print('Jogada Inválida {}'.format(jog_1))
        elif player_2 != 0 and player_2 != 1 and player_2 != 2 and player_2 != 3 and player_2 != 4:
            print('Jogada Inválida {}'.format(jog_2))
        else:
            break
    except ValueError:
        print('Jogada Inválida')
        continue
print("*" * 40)
print("Player_1 Escolheu: {}".format(entradasValidas[player_1]))
print("Player_2 Escolheu: {}".format(entradasValidas[player_2]))
print("*" * 40)
if player_1 == 0:  # jogador 1 jogou Pedra
    if player_2 == 0:
        print("Temos um Empate!")
    elif player_2 == 1 or player_2 == 4:
        print("O Jogador 2 Venceu!")
    elif player_2 == 2 or player_2 == 3:
        print("O Jogador 1 Venceu!")

if player_1 == 1:  # jogador 1 jogou Papel
    if player_2 == 0 or player_2 == 4:
        print("O Jogador 1 Venceu!")
    elif player_2 == 1:
        print("Temos um Empate!")
    elif player_2 == 2 or player_2 == 3:
        print("O Jogador 2 Venceu!")

if player_1 == 2:  # jogador 1 jogou Tesoura
    if player_2 == 0:
        print("O Jogador 2 Venceu!")
    elif player_2 == 1 or player_2 == 3 or player_2 == 4:
        print("O Jogador 1 Venceu!")
    elif player_2 == 2:
        print("Temos um Empate!")


if player_1 == 3:  # jogador 1 jogou Lagarto
    if player_2 == 0 or player_2 == 2:
        print("O Jogador 2 Venceu!")
    elif player_2 == 1 or player_2 == 4:
        print("O jogador 1 Venceu!")
    elif player_2 == 3:
        print("Temos um Empate!")


if player_1 == 4:  # jogador 1 jogou Esponja
    if player_2 == 0 or player_2 == 2:
        print("O Jogador 1 Venceu!")
    elif player_2 == 1 or player_2 == 3:
        print("O Jogador 2 Venceu!")
    elif player_2 == 4:
        print("Temos um Empate!")


print("")
print("*" * 40)
```

Comment: Muito Obrigada! Eu tava achando que precisava colocar um loop mesmo, mas não estava conseguindo implementar. Me ajudou muito! Consegui até criar outro loop para jogar novamente kkk